Show definition of key terms within cells on hover
I have a sharepoint list where I want to display definitions for key terms. I want them to show up when hovering over them. They are in a column of type multi row text.
Unlike in question here, these key terms are only one word in a cell. So hovering over the cell is not working for me.
Any advice on how I can achieve this?
